# QVideoWidget blocks mouse events on openGl scene on Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mouseevent

I've got a strange problem and need some help.I have a QMediaPlayer, QVideoWidget on a QDialog,
this QDialog displays videos and some text (nothing special) .
 The QDialog is shown over a QMainWindow ( its the main window of the program ).
 The QMainWindow contains a QWidget that has an openGl context.
 Everything works fine but as soon as the video on the QDialog is played, the mouse events are blocked on the OpenGl scene.
 As if playing the video on the QDialog disable mouse events on the OpenGl scene of the QMainWindow.

Info : I'm programming with Qt 5.6.1 clang 64bit

Maybe any one has tried to do something like this and could help with some advice?

Comment: it will be good if you could share some example code that is not working.